# How to deal with broken reference to compiled method?

Tags: stored-procedures, h2, stored-functions

In H2, we can make reference to compiled method in java classes, and create alias in the database.

My question is: will this reference also deleted when the java classes are deleted? Or, this the reference will stay put?

Answer (score 1):

The reference will stay, but the method will not work until the compiled code is available.